# Animated div appears to erect from bottom-right with transform-origin set to center

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I want to scale a div while still having it centered via. translate(-50%, -50%). This works for the most part, but it's as if the `transform` in the div is being ignored. When the animation occurs, the div scales and centers itself, but it looks like the div is "popping up" (scaling) from its bottom-right corner (as if the transformation weren't there before the animation was set).

```
@keyframes scaleAnimation
{
    from
    {
        transform: scale(0.75) translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    to
    {
        transform: scale(1) translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
}

.parentClass
{   
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    transform-origin: center;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    
    animation: scaleAnimation 0.3s;
}
```

What is a solution that (ideally) requires no JavaScript?

Comment: center then scale

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks! You're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 2):

In the `transforms` order matters. I edited your code. Hope this is what you're looking for:

```css
@keyframes scaleAnimation
{
    from
    {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.75) ;
    }
    to
    {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    }
}

.parent-class
{   
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #4565ff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    transform-origin: center center;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    animation: scaleAnimation 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-class"></div>
```